# ExtJS6 Extending Components

Tags: extjs6-classic

If I declare a custom component, how to I correctly apply changes to the properties when I create an extension of the component?  For example:

```
Ext.define('GridForm',{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    initComponent: function(){  
        Ext.apply(this,{
            title: 'This a test window!'
            ,height: 400
            ,width: 400       
        });
        this.callParent();
    }    
});
Ext.define('LedDataForm',{
    extend: 'GridForm',
    initComponent: function(){
        Ext.apply(this,{
            title: 'OK, I want to change it to this.'
        });        
        this.callParent();
    }
});
Ext.application({
    name : 'MyApp',
    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('LedDataForm').show();
    }
});
```

In this example, I simply want to change the title of the window when I create "LedDataForm". All comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write the configs whatever you want to override in init function, instead give it as a default config.

```
Ext.define('GridForm',{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    title: 'This a test window!',// Give this as configs rather than in init function
    initComponent: function(){  
        Ext.apply(this,{
            width:400,
            height:400
        });
        this.callParent();
    }    
});
Ext.define('LedDataForm',{
    extend: 'GridForm',
    title: 'OK, I want to change it to this.',
    initComponent: function(){
        Ext.apply(this,{
        });        
    this.callParent();
    }
});
Ext.application({
    name : 'MyApp',
    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('LedDataForm',{
            title:'testing'
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

```
Ext.define('GridForm',{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    title: 'This a test window!',
    height: 400,
    width: 400         
});
Ext.define('LedDataForm',{
    extend: 'GridForm',
    title: 'OK, I want to change it to this.'
});
Ext.application({
    name : 'MyApp',
    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('LedDataForm').show();
    }
});
```

Simple static configuration can be applied to the class body (2nd argument passed to `Ext.define`).

`initComponent` is usually only necessary if you need to calculate values or execute initialization logic.

Also, you could take a look here as it explains a lot: [The Class System](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/guides/core_concepts/classes.html).